# AngularJS: Find specific item in list of items / if statement in ng-class

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, if-statement, ng-class

I want to highlight the current user in a list of all users. My code looks like this.

```
<div class='user' ng-repeat='user in users'>
  <span class='name'>{{ user.displayName }}</span>
</div>
```

I have `currentUser.id` that I want to compare to `user.id` as I loop them through and perhaps add a class when the two match. I would like to do something like this in theory:

```
ng-class='highlight: if user.id == currentUser.id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ng-class='{highlight: user == currentUser}'
```

Comment: I had to use user.id and currentUser.id though. I guess the two objects aren't exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Gruff Bunny is correct.

Another way to do it that gets the logic a little more out of the DOM is to do the comparison in the controller or a directive and then assign the class with addClass.